# Cognito Form quit sending to my e-mail

Tags: cognito-forms

I've been using my Cognito form since the beginning of August and it has been sending me notifications to my e-mail up until this morning.  I only have 108 submissions.  Why would it stop notifying me?  BTW- I've checked my junk mail just in case it started being marked as spam but it's not going there either.

Comment: I am a developer for Cognito Forms. In order for us to help with this we do need to ask for account specific information: Email Address, and Organization Name. Could you submit a Bug Report to our support system with this information?

Comment: I just submitted a Bug Report.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. We did experience some down time with our email provider on 8/27/14. We were able to identify and resolve the problem and have taken steps to ensure that the problem will not occur again. Users still had the ability to submit forms, only email notifications were affected. We apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused.